# Is it possible to use cucumber with KIF?

Tags: testing, cucumber, automated-tests, kif-framework

We are deciding on which framework to use to test our iOS app.  We are mainly deciding between Frank and KIF.  I know Frank and Calabash can use cucumber.  I want to know if there is a way to use KIF with cucumber.  Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, KIF cannot be used with Cucumber.

If you would like to use KIF with BDD, have a look at Kiwi: 
https://github.com/blazingcloud/Kiwi

Kiwi is a BDD framework for iOS that should work well with KIF, here's a blogpost with more details about how they integrate:
http://blog.blazingcloud.net/2012/05/11/keys-to-ios-testing-kif-and-kiwi/

Comment: The links above are now broken but you can find out about a helper that was written called Kiwi-Kif [here](https://github.com/garnett/Kiwi-KIF)

Answer (score 1):

Try BDD for iOS tool: Kiwi https://github.com/kiwi-bdd/Kiwi and  https://github.com/garnett/Kiwi-KIF